# Apache POI streaming write XLSX directly to IO

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a web application where I want to return XLSX with a huge number of records without OOM. I want to write every page to OutputStream and flush in the loop. The problem is that I get an exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.implWrite(BufferedWriter.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:278) ~[na:na]
```

Is it possible to write data to OS page by page or only possible way is loading everything to memory?

My code is:

```
  public void export(final OutputStream os)  {
        
        try (SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1)) {

            final SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                final SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
                final SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("Test");

                try {
                    workbook.writeAvoidingTempFiles(os);
                    os.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.info("Error", e);
                }

            }
            workbook.dispose();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}

public void export(final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        
        try (TestBook workbook = new TestBook()) {

            final SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                final SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
                final SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("Test");
                workbook.write(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
                httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller code:

```java
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, path = "/1")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download1() {
 return ResponseEntity .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=\"" +
                       "test" +
                        ".xlsx\"")
                .body(exportService::export);
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, path = "/2")
    public void download2(final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {

        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=\"" +
                "test2" +
                ".xlsx\"");

        exportService.export(httpServletResponse);
    }
```

```
static class TestBook extends SXSSFWorkbook {
        public TestBook() {
            super(-1);
        }
    }
```

originam write method looks like:

```
    public void write(OutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        flushSheets();

        //Save the template
        File tmplFile = TempFile.createTempFile("poi-sxssf-template", ".xlsx");
        boolean deleted;
        try {
            try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tmplFile)) {
                _wb.write(os);
            }

            //Substitute the template entries with the generated sheet data files
            try (
                    ZipSecureFile zf = new ZipSecureFile(tmplFile);
                    ZipFileZipEntrySource source = new ZipFileZipEntrySource(zf)
            ) {
                injectData(source, stream);
            }
        } finally {
            deleted = tmplFile.delete();
        }
        if (!deleted) {
            throw new IOException("Could not delete temporary file after processing: " + tmplFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The stacktrace provides no clues as to a problem (other than attempting to write to a closed writer), and given it is a writer (which is for text data), it is unlikely to be related to an Excel sheet, as that is binary data. The stacktrace also doesn't include any elements of POI or your application code. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: And yes, it is possible to write Excel sheets with little memory overhead, if you use the streaming variant (e.g. `SXSSFWorkbook`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I used that but still the same issue is. I received only single value in file

Comment: Can you also show the initialization and concrete type of your OutputStream `os` ? Note: the [`writeAvoidingTempFiles`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#writeAvoidingTempFiles-java.io.OutputStream-) method is marked `@Beta`, do you get the same error when using `write` instead.

Comment: First and foremost, check your code executed before for any use of `close()` on the output-stream - as hinted by Mark already.

Comment: The OutputStream type is org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream. 
I didn't get the different issue when I used to write instead writeAvoidTempFiles, but my assumption was that maybe some of the internal classes close a stream.

Comment: Both methods - the same type of outputstream

Comment: How come you pass `httpServletResponse` to your `export` method when it takes an `OutputStream`? Are you calling a different `export` method than the one you're showing us?

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot add second version of method

Comment: Can you show the `TestBook.write` method?

Comment: This is standard method because I want to some how hack this method but at end of the end I kept original method.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard method" and "original method"? In particular, does it use try-with-resources on the stream that is passed to it?

Comment: Updated description. You can see that there is not override this method...

Comment: Have you considered an async API? The initial request specifies the inputs and a callback address. The xlsx is produced asynchronously and POSTed to the callback address when ready. There is also this sample - https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java that might provide a synchronous solution.

Comment: You must note that xlsx file format is not designed for smooth streaming - it is basically a zip file with multiple files contained within it, that have linked data. If you want to stream large data, you should consider a more streamable format like CSV.

Comment: Async API doesn't help in that case because an issue is that if you have a million of records you have to put all of them into memory. Jackson has a streaming approach for CSV and is possible to flush the buffer after some page and that doesn't allocate memory so much. Time is not a problem but memory allocation does it.

Answer (score 0):

Your workbook is a subclass of `SXSSFWorkbook`. With that kind of class, you shouldn't call `write()` in a loop with the same output stream, because, as you can see from the source code, it passes the stream to `injectData` which wraps the stream into a ZipOutputStream, writes to it and then closes the ZipOutputStream which causes the underlying stream (*your* stream) to also be closed.

The second iteration of your loop then calls `write()` with an already-closed output stream.

You should take the `write()` call outside of your for-loop and call it just after the loop.

Comment: Okay you write, but I want to return the stream of data to my client not wait to load all data from the source put it to Workbook, and return it to the client. 
What I want to achieve is to return all data from the source page by page to the workbook and return it to the client.  Because i can have a million of records, with min 150 columns. It needs a lot of memory but I want to this in "streaming" way.

Comment: I see, I don't know how to accomplish this, unfortunately.